# How to implement derivative free optimization like Nelder meads in PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, scipy, mathematical-optimization

I am using `BetaGeoFitter` of `lifetimes` package which internally uses `scipy.optimize` method to optimize the likelihood function whose gradient function isn't known. `BetaGeoFitter` is an implementation of *Buy-Till-You-Die* model.
`BetaGeoFitter` internally calls Nelder mead's optimization which is based on simplex.

Is there any way to implement such optimizations in PySpark?

The likelihood function is as follows:

```
L(r, α, a, b |X = x, tx, T) = A1 * A2 * (A3 + δx>0 A4)
```

where

```
A1 = (Γ(r + x)*α^r)/Γ(r)
A2 = (Γ(a + b)*Γ(b + x))/(Γ(b)*Γ(a + b + x))
A3 = (1/(α + T))^(r+x)
A4 = (a/(b+x-1))*(1/(α + t_x))^(r+x)
```

My code looks like this:

```
from lifetimes import BetaGeoFitter
class MyBTYD_helper:

    def __init__(self, penalizer_coef=0.0):
        self.model = BetaGeoFitter(penalizer_coef=penalizer_coef)
        self.params = None

    def fit(self, data):
        self.model.fit(data['x'], data['t_x'], data['T'])
        self.params = [self.model.params_['a'],  self.model.params_['alpha'], self.model.params_['b'], \
                       self.model.params_['r']]
```

Comment: can you share some code and what you have tried?

Comment: @mtoto I have updated the details. Please check.